# vscode python interpreter failed to debug/run in venv in windows

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

vscode version: 1.21.1

python version: 2.7.14

---

Launch.json:

```
         {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
```

---

Workspace settings:

```
"python.pythonPath": "D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
```

or

```
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
```

---

Both failed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\summy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.2.1\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher_nodebug.py", line 10, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: No module named _socket
```

Intergrate Terninal install flask failed in venv:

```
(venv) PS D:\Projects\Python_Test> pip install flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "D:\Projects\Python_Test\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "d:\projects\python_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "d:\projects\python_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "d:\projects\python_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: No module named _socket
```

---

If I use interpreter in "C:\Python27\python.exe", It works fine.

But I find an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/691), but when I install newest vscode-python successfully by download zip, using yard cmd, won't work.

Everything works fine in win cmd.

Any suggestion?

---

sys.path in venv:

```
['', 'C:\\other-folders-on-the-path', 
'C:\\Python27', 
'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 
'C:\\Python27\\Scripts', 
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test', 
'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv\\DLLs', 
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv\\lib',
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv\\lib\\plat-win'
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv\\lib\\lib-tk',
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv\\Scripts', 
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv', 
'D:\\Projects\\Python_Test\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: To install the development build of the extension you can follow the instructions at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-build . But this failure is pretty weird; do you have any other Python settings in your settings.json? What is sys.path set to when the exception is triggered?

Comment: @BrettCannon sys.path list above

Comment: @BrettCannon after I copy  'DLLs' folder to '\venv' from 'C:\\Python27', everything works fine....but in win cmd, do not need to do this.

Comment: it seems the vscode's venv missing path: 'C:\Python27\DLLs', but I can't find a way to add it.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new virtualenv? And are you running the latest version of virtualenv?

Comment: @BrettCannon yes, I have tried these all

Comment: @BrettCannon modify launch.json/settings.json of "pythonPath" to abs path of venv python.exe again, it worked! But I don't know why.